# loading app.js in deviceReady sencha touch cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have an issue I'm using device APIs the problem is device.uuid can be available after document ready  and the sencha touch load app.js before document be ready so what I get when I use device.uuid in sencha code it appear null

tried to call this function by

```
<body onload="allJs();">

<script>
    function allJs(){           
                document.write('<script src="all.js"><\/script>');
            }
</script>
```

if I put document .write before the on load function sencha app load perfectly
without device.uuid

```
<body onload="allJs();">

<script>
    document.write('<script src="all.js"><\/script>');
    function allJs(){           
                //document.write('<script src="all.js"><\/script>');
            }
</script>
```

what should I do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get script asynchronously by using this functions

```
function lazyload() {
    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script'); 
    scriptTag.src = "//my_example.js"; // set the src attribute
    scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript'; // if you have an HTML5 website you may want to comment this line out
    scriptTag.async = true; // the HTML5 async attribute
    var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    headTag.appendChild(scriptTag);
}
```

and for phonegap or cordova ready use

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
        lazyload();
}, false);
```

you can use jQuery getScript function or create it by yourself, see the links in sources

sources :

https://chris.lu/article/read/506de698268c420f0d000004

http://jeremyhixon.com/snippet/loading-javascript-files-asynchronously/